# How to use regular expressions in to my example?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have similar data strings:

```
3/1/1/1 1461 IMIE_NAZWISKO -1 -1 {1 0 #1461*TRANSFORMATION GEOM*#1474 #1461*FUNCTION*DataText
3/1/2/1 1509 FUNKCJA -1 -1 {1 0 #1509*TRANSFORMATION GEOM*#1523 MATERIAL*#1522 #1509*FUNCTION*DataText
3/1/3/1 155045 WWW -1 -1 {1 0 #1550*TRANSFORMATION GEOM*#1563
3/2/1/1 1606 Noggi -1 0 {1 0 #1606*TRANSFORMATION GEOM*#1619 #1606*MASK_SOURCE
3/2/1/2/1 1636 FUNKCJA -1 0 {1 0 #1636*TRANSFORMATION GEOM*#1661 #1636*ANIMATION
3/2/1/2/2 16633 12_232A -1 0 {1 0 #1663*TRANSFORMATION GEOM*#1688 #1663*ANIMATION
3/2/2/1 1704 4040_ -1 0 {1 0 #1704*TRANSFORMATION GEOM*#1717
```

The first part will always look similar: 3/1/1/1 or 3/1/1/1/2/2 or 1/1, etc.

The second part after the space is always several digits: 1461 or 300 or 121212 or 32323232, etc.

The third part is important to me: NAME_SURNAME or FUNCTION or WWW or 12WW or 12_232A or 4040_
The rest of the sequence is not important.
I also thought about using regular expressions, but I couldn't encode it.
I also thought about using regular expressions, but I couldn't encode it.

Expected result:

```
IMIE_NAZWISKO
FUNKCJA
WWW
Noggi
FUNKCJA
12_232A
4040_
```

To achieve this, I used the following code for each line:

```
a = n.find('{')
b = n.find(' ', 11)
print(n[b:a-6].replace(' ',''))
```

Unfortunately, my solution is too sensitive to changes in the number of characters in the first and second elements.

My solution is:

```
data = str(data).split('}} {')
        for n in data:
            if 'GEOM' in str(n) or 'ControlText' in str(n):
                i = n.find('GEOM')
                a = n.find('{')
                n = n[:a]
                pattern = r'\b(\w+)\s+-1\b'
                match = re.search(pattern, n)
                if match:
                    matched_group = match.group(1)
                    items.append(matched_group)
                else:
                    None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the "third part"

```
def get_third_word(input_string):
    # Split the string into words based on spaces
    words = input_string.split()

    # Check if the string has at least three words
    if len(words) >= 3:
        # Return the third word
        return words[2]
    else:
        print("NO MATCH WAS FOUND FOR ",input_string)
        return None

# Example usage:
input_string = "3/1/1/1 1461 IMIE_NAZWISKO -1 -1 {1 0 #1461*TRANSFORMATION GEOM*#1474 #1461*FUNCTION*DataText"
result = get_third_word(input_string)
print(result)
```

My second and worse solution:

I wish I have asked before I started coding but, I assumed the "fourth part" would always have -1 as it is the case in your code, so this solution finds the first -1 then finds the first word before the -1. Use this function while iterating over the relevant part of your dataframe(?)

```
import re

def extract_name(input_string):
    # Define a regular expresion pattern to find the word before -1
    pattern = r'\b(\w+)\s+-1\b'
    
    # Search for the pattern in the input string
    match = re.search(pattern, input_string)
    
    # if a match is found, return the captured word
    if match:
        return match.group(1)
    else:
        print("NO MATCH WAS FOUND FOR ",input_string)
        return None

# Example usage
input_string = "3/1/1/1 1461 IMIE_NAZWISKO -1 -1 {1 0 #1461*TRANSFORMATION GEOM*#1474 #1461*FUNCTION*DataText"
result = extract_name(input_string)
print(result)
#Now you only need to iterate the content in your data, if you need further help let me know while sharing
#the format of your dataframe(or whatever it is) so I can help you in doing that step as well
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `split()` the line and take position [2], see also [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
with open("sample.txt", "r") as f:
    text_list = f.readlines()
    
for row in text_list:
    try:
        print(row.split()[2])
    except:
        print("finished")
```

Output:

```
IMIE_NAZWISKO
FUNKCJA
WWW
Noggi
FUNKCJA
12_232A
4040_
finished
```

If you don't like the try and exception part, as an alternative:

```
for row in text_list:
    if len(row.split(maxsplit=3)) > 2:
        print(row.split(maxsplit=3)[2])
```